# Worker Threads On Single Core Device

Tags: android, multithreading, process

I have reposted [my question from Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58215/worker-threads-on-single-core-device) here, as this is more of a programming question, and it was recommended.
Anyway. Here it is:

I am making an app, that changes the build.prop of key values for a ROM. However, Android often gives me an ANR warning, as I am doing all the work on the UI thread. On the Android documentation, it tells me that I should use worker threads, and not do any work in the UI thread. But, I am building this system app to go with a ROM for a single core device.

Why would I want to use worker threads, as isn't this less efficient? As, Android has to halt the UI thread, load the worker thread, and when the UI is used again, halt the worker thread and load the UI thread again. Isn't this less efficient?

So, Should I use worker threads (Which slows the UI thread down anyway) or just do all of my work on the UI thread *Even if the application UI is really slow)?

Comment: Implement your code using whatever the common best practice is. In this instance use worker thread(s).

Comment: don't worry about cores. the scheduler will allow your worker thread to run when the ui thread is not working, allowing a smooth user experience. If your UI is slowed down by worker threads, reduce the number/priority of these.

Comment: Use a worker thread.  Reduce its priority below that of the UI.  Result - UI responsive as normal and work still gets done in, (nearly), the same time.

Comment: @MartinJames, I have no idea how to do that, I think I have more reading to do in the documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your users were robots, your logic would make perfect sense.** No context switching equals (very slightly) less overall computation time. You could benchmark it and see how much exactly.

However, in the present (and near future) your users will most likely be humans and with that you need to start thinking of psychology: A moving progress bar or responsiveness in general will give your users the impression that the the task is actually taking a shorter time than without any sort of feedback. The subjective speed is much higher *with* feedback.

There exist numerous papers on the subject of subjective speed, the [first one](http://chrisharrison.net/projects/progressbars2/ProgressBarsHarrison.pdf) I could find on the web has a nice comparison of progress bars in [a video](http://www.chrisharrison.net/index.php/Research/ProgressBars2) (basically, some bars seem to go faster than others, thus reducing the subjective overall wait time).

Answer (score 1):

Use worker threads.

As you've said, doing everything on the UI thread locks your UI until the operation is completed. This means you can't update progress, can't handle input events (such as the user pressing a cancel button), etc.

Your concern about the speed of context switching is misplaced - this happens all the time anyway, as core system processes and other apps run in the background. Some quick Googling shows that context [switching a thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_switching_latency) within the same process is [typically faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440128/thread-context-switch-vs-process-context-switch) than a process-level context switch anyway. There is *slightly* more overhead introduced by creating the threads and then the subsequent context switches, but it's likely to be minute - especially if you only have the 1 thread doing the work. For the reasons I've listed above alone (UI updates and the ability to accept user input), take the few-millisecond overall performance hit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you sort of lost me at the second sentence in the last paragraph - sorry, I'm a noob!

Comment: No worries! [Context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) is what you described as stopping the UI thread and loading the worker thread, and back again. It might be worthwhile reading about [how threads differ from processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#How_threads_differ_from_processes).

Comment: Ok, I will look into that later :) 

Thanks