# The effects of heavy thread consumption on ARM (4-core A72) vs x86 (2-core i5)

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system, arm, multiprocessing, grand-central-dispatch

I have a realtime linux desktop application (written in C) that we are porting to ARM (4-core Cortex v8-A72 CPUs). Architecturally, it has a combination of high-priority explicit pthreads (6 of them), and a couple GCD(libdispatch) worker queues (one concurrent and another serial).

My concerns come in two areas:

- I have heard that ARM does not hyperthread the way that x86 can and therefore my 4-cores will already be context switching to keep up with my 6 pthreads (and background processes). What kind of performance penalty should I expect from this?

  - I have heard that I should expect these ARM context-switches to be less efficient than x86. Is that true?
  - A couple of the pthreads are high-priority handlers for fairly rare-ish events, does this change the prospects much?(i.e. they are sitting on a `select` statement)
- My bigger concern comes from the impact of GCD in this application. My understanding of the inner workings of GCD is a that it is a dynamically scaled threadpool that interacts with the scheduler, and will try to add more threads to suit the load. It sounds to me like this will have an almost exclusively negative impact on performance in my scenario. (I.E. in a system whose cores are fully consumed) Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on anything x86-architecture related (so hopefully someone more experienced can chime in) but here are a few high level responses to your questions.

> I have heard that ARM does not hyperthread the way that x86 can [...]

Correct, hyperthreading is a proprietary Intel chip design feature. There is no analogous ARM silicon technology that I am aware of.

> [...] and therefore my 4-cores will already be context switching to keep up with my 6 pthreads (and background processes). What kind of performance penalty should I expect from this? [...]

This is not *necessarily* the case, although it could very well happen in many scenarios. It really depends more on what the nature of your per-thread computations are...are you just doing lots of hefty computations, or are you doing a lot of blocking/waiting on IO? Either way, this degradation will happen on both architectures and it is more of a general thread scheduling problem. In hyperthreaded Intel world, each "physical core" is seen by the OS as two "logical cores" which share the same resources but have their own pipeline and register sets. The wikipedia article states:

> Each logical processor can be individually halted, interrupted or directed to execute a specified thread, independently from the other logical processor sharing the same physical core.[7]
>
> Unlike a traditional dual-processor configuration that uses two separate physical processors, the logical processors in a hyper-threaded core **share the execution resources. These resources include the execution engine, caches, and system bus interface;** the sharing of resources allows two logical processors to work with each other more efficiently, and allows a logical processor to borrow resources from a stalled logical core (assuming both logical cores are associated with the same physical core). A processor stalls when it is waiting for data it has sent for so it can finish processing the present thread. The degree of benefit seen when using a hyper-threaded or multi core processor depends on the needs of the software, and how well it and the operating system are written to manage the processor efficiently.[7]

So if a few of your threads are constantly blocking on I/O then this might be where you would see more improvement in a 6-thread application on a 4 physical core system (for both ARM and intel x86) since theoretically this is where hyperthreading would shine....a thread blocking on IO or on the result of another thread can "sleep" while still allowing the other thread running on the same core to do work without the full overhead of an thread switch (experts please chime in and tell me if I'm wrong here).

But 4-core ARM vs 2-core x86... assuming all else equal (which obviously is not the case, in reality clock speeds, cache hierarchy etc. all have a huge impact) then I think that really depends on the nature of the threads. I would imagine this drop in performance could occur if you are just doing a ton of *purely cpu-bound* computations (i.e. the threads never need to wait on anything external to the CPU). But If you are doing a lot of blocking I/O in each thread, you might show significant speedups doing up to probably 3 or 4 threads per logical core.

Another thing to keep in mind is the cache. When doing lots of cpu-bound computations, a thread switch has the possibility to blow up the cache, resulting in much slower memory access initially. This will happen across both architectures. This isn't the case with I/O memory, though. But if you are not doing a lot of blocking things however, then the extra overhead with threading will just make it slower for the reasons above.

> I have heard that I should expect these ARM context-switches to be less efficient than x86. Is that true?

A hardware context switch is a hardware context switch, you push all the registers to the stack and flip some bits to change execution state. So no, I don't believe either is "faster" in that regard. **However**, for a single physical core, techniques like hyperthreading makes a "context switch" in the Operating Systems sense (I think you mean switching between threads) much faster, since the instructions of both programs were already being executed in parallel on the same core.

I don't know anything about GCD so can't comment on that.

At the end of the day, I would say your best shot is to benchmark the application on both architectures. See where your bottlenecks are. Is it in memory access? Keeping the cache hot therefore is a priority. I imagine that 1-thread per core would always be optimal for any scenario, if you can swing it.

Some good things to read on this matter:

1. https://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html
2. https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/
3. [Optimal number of threads per core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718465/optimal-number-of-threads-per-core)
4. [Thread context switch Vs. process context switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440128/thread-context-switch-vs-process-context-switch)

Comment: "A hardware context switch is a hardware context switch, you push all the registers to the stack and flip some bits to change execution state." It's worth pointing out -- [As with other tasks performed in hardware, one would expect this to be rather fast; however, mainstream operating systems, including Windows and Linux, do not use this feature.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch#Hardware_vs._software)